# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on Trekstore SurfTab duo W2 / Cube i7

Tags: wireless, gnome, bluetooth, multi-touch, touchscreen

Hello askubuntu community,

after installing Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS on the TrekStore SurfTab duo W2 - which is similar to the Cube i7 according to xda - ,so it's a dual Tablet / Netbook, there are a couple of problems.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=7b6e0bf20d90eb4036cf4a29dee00758&p=64935922&postcount=2385

The machine runs the latest 16.04 Ubuntu LTS base with GNOME 3.20 and the recent 4.6 Kernel.

The problems are:

1. There is no WiFi connection. The systems show the network but it somehow can't connect to it.
2. There is no bluetooth at all. 
   It is probably a driver issue, since lsusb shows an unnamed device which is according to wikidevi a:

   [2b54:5600] - Emdoor AP6356SD

   Broadcom BCM4356A2 (Bluetooth USB module)
   BCM4356A2_001.003.015.0046.0154 (v4250)

are there any drivers for it?

3. Is it possible to configure multi-touch gestures for the touchscreen with a program? Like pinch to zoom, etc.
   Gestures work very well on the touchpad though.

Thanks in advance.
PeBi

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install firmware-brcm80211 package
2. Accorging my information, this is Broadcom BCM4356A2 based device that not yet supported in Linux kernel. Bluetooth subsystem not even know these vendor & device ID.

Adding this support is fairly easy. But you need some knowledge and skills of compiling and installing modified kernel source. Find this snippet of code in drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c of Linux kernel and add these strings:

```
/* Intel Bluetooth USB Bootloader (RAM module) */
{ USB_DEVICE(0x8087, 0x0a5a),
  .driver_info = BTUSB_INTEL_BOOT | BTUSB_BROKEN_ISOC },
/* POST CODE HERE */

/* Emdoor AP6356SD BCM4356A2 (Broadcom BCM4356A2 based device) */
{ USB_DEVICE(0x2b54, 0x5600), .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM }, 

/* END OF CODE */    

{ } /* Terminating entry */
```

And compile and install it.

Also, you require firmware BCM4356A2-2b54-5600.hcd, which can be obtained here - https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware